# Got "exe has stopped working. Close program" in VS 2013 Premium edition after updating from VS 2008

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have developed VB.Net windows application VS 2008. 
Now I am updating that application in VS 2013 Premium edition with .Net framework 4.5.1. After updating suddenly I am getting "exe has stopped working. Close program.". At any time anywhere. 
And also while debugging I got System.accessViolation error.
I tried to update framework 4.5.1 to 4.5.2. I also tried to Update target CPU from "Any CPU" to 
"X86" as well as "X64". But getting same error.
But after updating framework 4.5.1 to 3.5 it is working fine in VS 2013 Premium edition. 
Please suggest me how can I run my program in framework 4.5.1 or onward versions.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: When you switch between framework versions are you doing a Clean Solution to get rid of all the old executables?

Comment: Yes Rob we have already clean solution before updating freamwork

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on one of my projects. How I fixed it was to create a brand new solution using the new version of VS and then add the classes and the external dependencies to the new solution.

After I did that everything worked like a charm.

Comment: we tried same thing with .net 4.5.2, but getting same issue.

Comment: Are there many dependencies/3rd party API's and Libraries? Have you confirmed that all of them work with 4.5.2?

Comment: we are using some references of other applications, and we had converted all those dll's (to .net 4.5.2), but still its not working, showing same error.

Comment: It is Library Management Application which manage Book/Manuscripts/Magazines. it also manages Publishers/Authors/Readers.

we are using some references of our other applications, and we had converted all those dll's (to same .net framework as Library Management Application ).

We have used MS Office Introp Word 15 DLL to read Word file from our Application.

We have also used Acrobat Browser Control Type Library 1.0 DLL to show PDF in our Application.

Comment: If you've tried creating a brand new application from scratch with 4.5 and "Any CPU" (manually dragging and dropping the classes into the solutions explorer) - and it works with 3.5 but not 4.5 - then you definitely have a reference issue.

Comment: but before adding reference, we convert those all referenced application to .net 4.5.2 and then add reference.

Comment: how did you convert them? are they .dll/.exes that were also written by your group?

Comment: There are class libraries and we are adding that library projects dlls after updating into 4.5.2. And also we are using some third party dlls.